# List iterator fails to return an iterator

Tags: c++

I am trying to rewrite some parts of Prim's algorithm without a heap and represented with a list of adjacency from here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/prims-algorithm-using-priority_queue-stl/

This is what I have:

```
// PRIM MST fara heap lista adiacenta

#include<bits/stdc++.h> 
using namespace std; 
# define INF 0x3f3f3f3f 

// pereche int int denumita iPair
struct Edge {
    int destination;
    int weight;
};

Edge newEdge(int destination, int weight) {
    return { destination, weight };
}

// un graf directionat cu reprezentare prin lista de adiacenta
class Graph 
{ 
    int V; // Numar de noduri

    // Lista care retine nodul si costul muchiei pentru fiecare pereche
    list< Edge > *adj; 

public: 
    Graph(int V) {
        this->V = V;
        adj = new list<Edge> [V]; 
    }; // constructorul

    // adauga o muchie grafului
    void addEdge(int from, int to, int weight){
        adj[from].push_back(newEdge(to, weight)); // http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/push_back/ pentru push back
        adj[to].push_back(newEdge(from, weight)); 
    };

    // // Printeaza drumul cel mai scurt din sursa la toate celelalte noduri
    void primMST(int numberElemOp){
        // Creaza o coada de prioritati pentru a stoca toate nodurile.
        // Sintaxa aparent o poti vedea aici http://geeksquiz.com/implement-min-heap-using-stl/ de ce e cum e
        priority_queue< Edge, vector <Edge> , greater<Edge> > pq; 

        int src = 0; // Nodul 0 devine sursa
        numberElemOp += 1;

        // Creem un vector unde sa stocam cheile si le initializam cu infinit
        vector<int> key(V, INF); 

        // Pentru stocarea array-ului de parinti
        vector<int> parent(V, -1); 

        // Vector care ne arata ce noduri au fost incluse in mst
        vector<bool> inMST(V, false); 

        // Baga nodul parinte in coada de prioritati si face cheia 0
        pq.push(newEdge(0, src));
        key[src] = 0; 

        numberElemOp += 2;

        /* Pana cand coada devine vida */
        while (!pq.empty()) 
        { 

            int u = pq.top().destination; 
            pq.pop(); 

            inMST[u] = true; // Include nodul in MST

            // // i este utilizat pentru a lua toate nodurile vecine
            printf("HIIIIIIIII");
            list< Edge >::iterator i;
            printf("HIIIIIIIII");

            numberElemOp += 4;
            for (i = adj[u].begin(); i != adj[u].end(); ++i) 
            { 
                // Ia numele si costul nodului vecin cu u
                int v = (*i).destination; 
                int weight = (*i).weight; 

                // If v is not in MST and weight of (u,v) is smaller 
                // than current key of v 

                // Daca v nu este in MST si costul muchiei (u,v) este mai mic decat cheia lui v
                numberElemOp += 5;
                if (inMST[v] == false && key[v] > weight) 
                { 
                    // Updateaza cheia lui v
                    key[v] = weight; 
                    pq.push(newEdge(key[v], v)); 
                    parent[v] = u;
                    numberElemOp += 7;
                } 
            } 
        } 

        // Printeaza muchiile msg-ului
        for (int i = 1; i < V; ++i) 
            printf("%d - %d\n", parent[i], i); 

        printf("Numar operatii elementare: %d", numberElemOp);
    }
}; 

int main() 
{ 
    int numberElemOp;
    // creaza un graf
    printf("HIIIIIIIII");
    int V = 9;

    numberElemOp += 1;
    Graph g(V); 

    g.addEdge(0, 1, 4); 
    g.addEdge(0, 7, 8); 
    g.addEdge(1, 2, 8); 
    g.addEdge(1, 7, 11); 
    g.addEdge(2, 3, 7); 
    g.addEdge(2, 8, 2); 
    g.addEdge(2, 5, 4); 
    g.addEdge(3, 4, 9); 
    g.addEdge(3, 5, 14); 
    g.addEdge(4, 5, 10); 
    g.addEdge(5, 6, 2); 
    g.addEdge(6, 7, 1); 
    g.addEdge(6, 8, 6); 
    g.addEdge(7, 8, 7); 

    g.primMST(numberElemOp); 

    return 0; 
}
```

The problem seems to be with the list iterator at the moment. The error I am shown is something big and ugly which I don't really seem to figure out:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/string:48:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/istream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/sstream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/complex:45,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/ccomplex:38,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/5/bits/stdc++.h:52,
                 from prog.cpp:3:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_function.h: In instantiation of 'bool std::greater<_Tp>::operator()(const _Tp&, const _Tp&) const [with _Tp = Edge]':
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/predefined_ops.h:144:37:   required from 'bool __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_val<_Compare>::operator()(_Iterator, _Value&) [with _Iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Edge*, std::vector<Edge> >; _Value = Edge; _Compare = std::greater<Edge>]'
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_heap.h:129:48:   required from 'void std::__push_heap(_RandomAccessIterator, _Distance, _Distance, _Tp, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Edge*, std::vector<Edge> >; _Distance = long int; _Tp = Edge; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_val<std::greater<Edge> >]'
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_heap.h:199:23:   required from 'void std::push_heap(_RAIter, _RAIter, _Compare) [with _RAIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Edge*, std::vector<Edge> >; _Compare = std::greater<Edge>]'
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_queue.h:510:16:   required from 'void std::priority_queue<_Tp, _Sequence, _Compare>::push(std::priority_queue<_Tp, _Sequence, _Compare>::value_type&&) [with _Tp = Edge; _Sequence = std::vector<Edge>; _Compare = std::greater<Edge>; std::priority_queue<_Tp, _Sequence, _Compare>::value_type = Edge]'
prog.cpp:56:26:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_function.h:377:20: error: no match for 'operator>' (operand types are 'const Edge' and 'const Edge')
       { return __x > __y; }
                    ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_algobase.h:64:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/ios:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/istream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/sstream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/complex:45,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/ccomplex:38,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/5/bits/stdc++.h:52,
                 from prog.cpp:3:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_pair.h:233:5: note: candidate: template<class _T1, class _T2> constexpr bool std::operator>(const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&, const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&)
     operator>(const pair<_T1, _T2>& __x, const pair<_T1, _T2>& __y)
     ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_pair.h:233:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/string:48:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/istream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/sstream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/complex:45,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/ccomplex:38,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/5/bits/stdc++.h:52,
                 from prog.cpp:3:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_function.h:377:20: note:   'const Edge' is not derived from 'const std::pair<_T1, _T2>'
       { return __x > __y; }
                    ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_algobase.h:67:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/ios:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/istream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/sstream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/complex:45,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/ccomplex:38,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/5/bits/stdc++.h:52,
                 from prog.cpp:3:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_iterator.h:310:5: note: candidate: template<class _Iterator> bool std::operator>(const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&, const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&)
     operator>(const reverse_iterator<_Iterator>& __x,
     ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_iterator.h:310:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/string:48:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/istream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/sstream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/complex:45,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/ccomplex:38,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/5/bits/stdc++.h:52,
                 from prog.cpp:3:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_function.h:377:20: note:   'const Edge' is not derived from 'const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>'
       { return __x > __y; }
                    ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_algobase.h:67:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/ios:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/istream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/sstream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/complex:45,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/ccomplex:38,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/5/bits/stdc++.h:52,
                 from prog.cpp:3:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_iterator.h:367:5: note: candidate: template<class _IteratorL, class _IteratorR> bool std::operator>(const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&, const std::reverse_iterator<_IteratorR>&)
     operator>(const reverse_iterator<_IteratorL>& __x,
     ^
     ^
```

However I am not sure why because it seems I am doing right what I am doing https://thispointer.com/c-different-ways-to-iterate-over-a-list-of-objects/

Anyone got any clues why this might happen?

Comment: What's unclear about that error message? You didn't define that `operator<()` function as required.

Comment: Which 'operator' function ?

Comment: The comparator. How are `Edge` compared if you don't specify it?

Comment: Also don't include `<bits/stdc++.h>`.

Comment: Ah, I think i understand what you are saying now, I need an compare function for the priority queue?

Comment: @LucianTarna `adj = new list<Edge> [V];` -- You used vector in other places, however you didn't use it here, as in: `std::vector<list<Edge>> arr;`.  Why?

Comment: I haven't written C in 7 years since my first year in faculty(and i've written C in total for about 6 month when i was learning OOP concepts). Not that good at it, never liked it. but thank you for the suggestion :D

Comment: @LucianTarna _"I need an compare function for the priority queue?"_ Of course you need that. _"I haven't written C in 7 years since my first year in faculty"_ Note that c and c++ are completely different languages.

Comment: The reason you should be using `vector` there are 1), Your `Graph` class instantly becomes copy correct, and 2) You have no way, unless you write a lot of extra code, to check if you ever go out-of-bounds of the allocated data when `arr` is a pointer.  If you write `arr[n]` and `n` is out-of-bounds, with `vector` you have `at()` to check these things, or the debug runtime may be able to check boundary accesses.  Using `new[]` and pointers, you have little to no chance of this being checked automatically.